# In Qt how do I reset the background colour of an item in a ListView from the Model?

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt I have a `QListView` that is using a custom Model class that contains the data to display. Based on the data, I want the background (and eventually the foreground/text) colour to be set to match the state of the data.

So far I have accomplished this by returning a `QBrush` with the selected `QColor` inside of a `QVariant` for the `Qt::BackgroundRole` in the `QAbstractListModel::data()` method, like so:

```
QVariant CustomListModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
  Item& item = findItem(index);
  if (item)
  {
    // ...
    if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
    {
      return QVariant(QBrush(item.color()));
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that I want to be able to reset the colour back to the widget's default background colour when the item's state becomes 'neutral', but I have been unable to find the correct instructions to do this. What is the canonical way to accomplish this?

Comment: Now thinking about it when adding things I've tried, I may have missed a required connection elsewhere which has prevented stuff from working as required. I will test it at work tomorrow and see what solution will work.

Comment: Ok, my bad, it was a problem on my end not propagating the state correctly elsewhere. I've fixed that and the colour setting and unsetting work easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this in your data method:

```
if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
{
    bool itemStateIsNeutral = ...

    if (itemStateIsNeutral) return QVariant();
    // else:

    return QVariant(QBrush(item.color()));
}
```

You might have to do return `QVariant(QBrush())` instead, I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Returning QVariant() is ok, as it means the model has no specific value for it